# How to create space between images in the gallery?

Tags: android, gallery

I have created a gallery in my android project. But in display the images of the gallery
don't have space in between each other. How I should create space between them. Please help 
me.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

android:spacing (in XML) or setSpacing(int) (in Java)

Comment: Can you please give an example of an int passed to setSpacing(). What does the int represent?

Comment: @kilaka Spacing is the pixels between items in the Gallery. [http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Gallery.html#setSpacing(int)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Gallery.html#setSpacing(int))

Answer (score 4):

You may use [`android:spacing`](http://d.android.com/reference/android/widget/Gallery.html#attr_android%3aspacing).